# List =null вместо копирования это Плохая практика?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Собственно есть два листа в разных скриптах в некий момент времени один должен стать эквивалентным другому
ну я и:

```
public void CopyMyList( List<GameObject> newList)
{
    if(oldList !=null)
    {

        oldList = null;
       oldList = newList;
    } }
```

Насколько это плохая практика и чем это может быть черевато?
PS
Пока всё работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Присваивание `null` не нужно. Вы всё равно следующей строкой затираете этот самый `null`. Ничего плохого в этом нет, просто лишняя операция.

Заметьте, что у вас вовсе не происходит копирования списка, несмотря на название функции. Поскольку `List<T>` — ссылочный тип, то вы просто записываете в `oldList` ссылку на тот же список, что приходит к вам в `newList`. Если вам реально нужна *копия* списка, проще всего сделать так:

```
public void CopyMyList( List<GameObject> newList)
{
    if (oldList != null) // я сохраняю ту же логику
       oldList = newList.ToList();
}
```

---

Как верно подсказывает @iluxa1810 в комментариях, даже при этом список будет всё ещё содержать ссылки на *те же самые объекты*, из изменения в этих объектах в списке `newList` будут «видны» и в списке `oldList`. Если это не то, что нужно, придётся склонировать и объекты. Для этого нужно в `GameObject` реализовать интерфейс [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx), и вместо `oldList = newList.ToList()` написать более сложное `oldList = newList.Select(o => (GameObject)o.Clone).ToList()`.

Comment: Я думаю, что стоит указать, что это не полная копия. Т.е если лист содержит в себе ссылочные объекты, то меняя объекты в одном листе, они будут так же меняться и в другом.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это да, но здесь возникает вопрос, что из ссылок внутри объекта считать «внутренней частью» самого объекта, а что — ссылками на внешние сущности. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне не нужно в данном случае истинное копирование. Просто нужно просто чтобы скрипт имел доступ к актуальному списку объектов.

Comment: @astion: Понял, тогда достаточно просто `oldList = newList`.

Answer (score 1):

C# сам очистит вам память, выделенную для старого списка, поэтому `oldList = null` можно вообще не писать.

Другое дело - что эти две переменные будут указывать на один и тот же список, и удаление элемента из одного скажется на другом (очень упрощенно говоря)

Comment: Я пробовал не писать - но в итоге почему то ничего никуда не копировалось - видать какие-то внутренние особенности Unity3d